# how to return SQL query result from webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I want to make a service which is able to return the result of sql query to client side in 3 tier achitecture. With huge size of table, I cannot turn result value into `String`(heap space error). So I tried return other types. I hope it could return `Vector<Vector<Object>>` type that `DefaultTableModel` can simply use, the webservice code like below

```
public Vector<Vector<String>> ReturnSet()
{
    try
    {    
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        SQL = "Select * from table";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        Check = pst.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = Check.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        Vector<Vector<String>> Vecs = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        Vector<String> cn = new Vector<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            cn.add(metaData.getColumnName(i+1));
        Vecs.add(cn);
        while (Check.next()) 
        {
            Vector<String> Vec = new Vector<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                Vec.add(Check.getString(i+1));
            Vecs.add(Vec);
        }
        return Vecs;
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

At client side, I used Netbeans IDE to created webservice client. the service generated code like below,

```
private static java.util.List<usesql.Vector> returnSet() {
    usesql.WS_Service service = new usesql.WS_Service();
    usesql.WS port = service.getWSPort();
    return port.returnSet();
}
```

But each time when I calling `returnSet()`, program just stuck, without error from log or console. My question is to make it work(type isn't limit), Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is more about the data-size. If the table is huge and contains a lot of data, it doesn't really make sense to return it per user request.

A lot of memory will be consumed on server. And what if many users request the data (call the web service) simultaneously?

In addition, maybe the client will be just overwhelmed by such a big amount of data and will go Out Of Memory.

Database also works hard here, trying to return all the data.

So I think you should reconsider the strategy of working with such a big amount of data. There are many interesting techniques for this.

1. Paging:

   Are you really sure that the client will need to see all the data?
   Maybe it makes sense to expose a couple of buttons (previous/next) and upon the click just to call the web service with some paging parameters
2. Dynamic Model:

   I might be wrong, but from the name of the class of table model, somehow I've deduced that you're using Swing (it doesn't really matter though, it can be web, SWT or whatsoever).

   In this case, maybe you should provide some kind of listener that would trigger the data loading in background (threads in Swing / AJAX in web) when user scrolls over the data.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I have one more question here.  Is there have a better way that faster than return String type? I think it cause too much time if it have to turn those data into a String.

Comment: Now I tried is make `Vector` serialize to a `String`. like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610608/java-web-services-and-returning-vectorvectorobject

Comment: Depending on the type of client and system requirements, you can use text (string), binary protocols (Thrift, Avro, Google Protobuf) and so forth. Binary protocols are more compact (you might transfer less data over wire + no HTTP Overhead) , but you might need to work hard on server to encode the data into binary stream. If you go binary - you won't get REST/Soap web services (in practice they work over HTTP). Bottom line, as I said, you better change the flow. Transferring huge amount of data is always a bad idea :)