# JAXB -EclipseLink MOXy Object type not getting marshalled correctly

Tags: jax-rs, eclipselink, moxy

```
public class ResposneMessage {

    private int status;
    private String code = "";
    private String message = "";
    private Object data;
}
```

The "DictType" is not marshaled:

```
{
  "code": "",
  "data": "com.testapp.model.DictType@7c9a897 com.testapp.model.DictType@43581423 com.testapp.model.DictType@217adb02 com.testapp.model.DictType@6ff992bb com.testapp.model.DictType@253e12c3 com.testapp.model.DictType@2644f34b com.testapp.model.DictType@51919e4a com.testapp.model.DictType@72deb289 com.testapp.model.DictType@27231e1b com.testapp.model.DictType@26fc6f1f com.testapp.model.DictType@7b42c644 com.testapp.model.DictType@7c8f695f com.testapp.model.DictType@43637313",
  "message": "",
  "status": 200
}
```

Default is not marshaling the `Object` type.

Comment: This is duplicate - please refer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818327/jaxb-how-should-i-marshal-complex-nested-data-structures

Comment: @kinshuk4 except that's not a duplicate at all but an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

An `Object` can not be marshalled to any meaningful JSON representation because the library responsible for marshalling the object uses reflection to do so. It seems to only look at the top-most class in the hierarchy you defined and marshalls whatever it finds in there.
Since there is nothing for `Object`, you just get its `.toString()` representation.

FWIW: The same happens when you try to marshall an interface or (abstract) superclass. You only see the properties the interface/superclass itself defines, in your marshalled output - regardless of what the descendant classes declare/define.
Take this example:

```java
public class SuperClass {
}

public class OtherClass extends SuperClass {
    public String someProperty = "test";
}

public class MarshallMe {
    public SuperClass classTest = new OtherClass();
}
```

This would marshall to just `"classTest":{}` because `SuperClass` doesn't have any properties of its own.

Comment: thanks, but how can i  do this using Moxy. Becuase the restful result is Object, so wen can return different result. we now using Jackson's ObjectMapper to generate json.